# Commutative diagrams for groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, universal-algebra, operads

You can present a group in a Cayley-like manner, replacing colors by explicit assignment of nodes to edges: while in a Cayley graph $x \circ y = z$ is presented like this:

[image]

you can also present it like this:

[image]

Now the group axioms can be stated like this:

- For each $x, y$ there is a unique $z$ with $x \circ y = z$, or: such that the following diagram holds ("commutes"):

[image]

- There is an $e$ such that for all $x$ it holds that $x\circ e = e \circ x = x$, or: such that the following two diagrams commute:

[image]

and for each $x$  there is a $x^{-1}$ such that $x \circ x^{-1} = x^{-1} \circ x = e$, or: such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

- For each $x, y, z$ it holds that $x \circ (y \circ z) = (x \circ y) \circ z$, or: such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

The last diagram is somewhat ugly, even when drawn in this most balanced way (I didn't find a more appealing and symmetric one).

But an astonishing symmetry arises, when we consider Abelian groups. Commutativity is expressed by the diagram:

[image]

and associativity becomes:

[image]

In the presence of commutativity, associativity seems to be related to commutativity (some sort of "second level commutativity").

> Can any use be made of this kind of diagrams, or is it
>   just vain baublery?

Comment: I guess your diagram for associativity in general groups is just a kind of ugly, because you draw it in two dimensions. In three dimensions you can put the squares as corners of tetrahedron and the circles on the edges ;-). (OK, the directions of the arrows are not so clear.)

Comment: It looks a bit like "sketches" to me, but I'm not an expert so shall merely mention it.  As for your comment about commutativity and associativity, associativity *is* commutativity.  It's commutativity of the operations $L_x$ and $R_z$ where $L_x$ is "multiply on the left by $x$" and $R_z$ is (you've guessed it), "multiply on the right by $z$".  I have a vague memory of seeing an article going into some detail about this.  Under commutativity, $R_z = L_z$ so we can rewrite $x(y z)$ as $x (z y)$ and $(x y) z$ as $z (x y)$ whereupon associativity becomes commutativity of $L_x$ and $L_z$.

Comment: I vote for baublery.

Answer (score 5):

These pictures are a way of writing a group as an algebra over an [operad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory).  The little square is the 2-ary operation, and the arrows are an indicator that makes the inputs distinguishable.

John Baez has written about operads using pictures similar to yours.  See for example [TWF week 191](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week191.html).

The relation between associativity and commutativity is similar to a fact seen in some books on vertex algebras, where one starts with an axiom like $x(yz) = y(xz)$ and after some power series manipulations deduces $x(yz) = (xy)z$.